# Vertx access response body

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to access the `HttpServerResponse` body that is written to perform validation. However, `ctx.response.endHandler(e -> ...)`/ `ctx.response.endBodyHandler(e> ...)` doesn't pass the body in, nor is there a `ctx.response.getBody` method. Is there another way to access the response body that is sent?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the `response` from within the server? If so, then could you validate whatever you are going to write **before** you put it in the response? If not (i.e. if this is about validating the response on receipt by the client) then you'd consume the response and perhaps serialise it into a representation which means something to the client and then validate _that_.

Comment: For example, I want to be able to attach to `router.route('/xyz/*')` and validate on the server any responses for those endpoints that the server may send. It's possible to view all `HttpServerRequests` for the endpoint and validate the body sent by the client, but no mechanism to read the body for any responses sent by the server before it reaches the client.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a vert.x web handler performing your validation and writing the response. It would collect the payload from the context.

So your main handler ends with:

```
rc.put("result", ...); 
rc.next();
```

Then your validation handler retrieve the result from the routing context, perform the validation and write the response (and may write an error response if the validation fails).